# Disable Button postback in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2

My JSF page is as follows

```
   <h:head>
        <title>Ajax Test</title>
    <h:outputScript name="giveEffect.js" library="jquery"/>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" library="jquery"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="div1">
        <h:button id="b1" onclick=" button1Click(this)" value="#{kp.firstname}"/>
    <h:button id="b2" onclick="button1Click(this)" value="#{kp.home}"/>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

button1Click is a jquery function which does ajax call and updates my page. But unable to see ajax update. Due to postback/jsf life cylce call, I changes are getting lost.

On inspecting the Dom using firebug. I found the  following code.

```
<div id="div1">
<input id="b1" type="button" value="Kar" onclick="button1Click(this); window.location.href='/AJAXTest/faces/index.xhtml'; return false;">
<input id="b2" type="button" value="Alike" onclick="button1Click(this); window.location.href='/AJAXTest/faces/index.xhtml'; return false;">
 </div>
```

Suppose I eliminate window.location.href='/AJAXTest/faces/index.xhtml' using firebug I get the expected output.

Is there any tag or mechanism to remove postback call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button component's outcome attribute is used to determine the target URL which is activated by onclick. The entire target URL string will be written out to the onclick attribute of the button as "window.location.href = ''". If you have a custom onclick method the window.location.href will be appended at the end of your script. Since you did not mention an outcome it will result in a GET request to your current view.

You can instead use
`<h:commandButton>` and mention type="button" like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="b1" onclick=" button1Click(this)" value="#{kp.firstname} "type="button">
```

[Documentation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/button.html)